# How do i find and replace something inside a quote?

Tags: go

I found this Go program which is going to find and remove text in a file and I need some help.

How do I modify this program to get the following and replace it?

I tried a couple of things but the issue is there is another quote inside of the string.

Current:

```
{"telephone_numbers":["1-
```

Future:

```
{"telephone_numbers":["+1-
```

Find and replace script.

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "io/ioutil"
        "os"
        "path/filepath"
        "strings"
)

func visit(path string, fi os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
                return err
        }

        if !!fi.IsDir() {
                return nil //
        }

        matched, err := filepath.Match("*.txt", fi.Name())
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
                return err
        }

        if matched {
                read, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
                if err != nil {
                        panic(err)
                }
                //fmt.Println(string(read))
                fmt.Println(path)

                newContents := strings.Replace(string(read), "old", "new", -1)

                fmt.Println(newContents)

                err = ioutil.WriteFile(path, []byte(newContents), 0)
                if err != nil {
                        panic(err)
                }
        }

        return nil
}

func main() {
        err := filepath.Walk(".", visit)
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
}
```

Comment: `if !!fi.IsDir()` -- what is that `!!` about?

Comment: i am still learing golang so i am not sure but the script works.

Comment: Why did you write something that you don't understand?

Comment: Also, minor terminology nit: That's not a script. Go is a compiled language, not a scripting language.

Comment: As for `!!` -- it looks like you're trying to coerce a truthy value into a literal boolean, but that makes no sense in Go, which doesn't have truthiness. So just remove that.

Answer (score -1):

This is the answer.

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "io/ioutil"
        "os"
        "path/filepath"
        "strings"
)

func visit(path string, fi os.FileInfo, err error) error {

        if err != nil {
                return err
        }

        if !!fi.IsDir() {
                return nil //
        }

        matched, err := filepath.Match("*.txt", fi.Name())

        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
                return err
        }

        if matched {
                read, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
                if err != nil {
                        panic(err)
                }
                //fmt.Println(string(read))
                fmt.Println(path)

                newContents := strings.Replace(string(read), `{"telephone_numbers":["1-`, `{"telephone_numbers":["+1-`, -1)

                fmt.Println(newContents)

                err = ioutil.WriteFile(path, []byte(newContents), 0)
                if err != nil {
                        panic(err)
                }

        }

        return nil
}

func main() {
        err := filepath.Walk(".", visit)
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
}
```